# How to read a file and then write to it with one open?

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a text file only have one number in it.

I would like to open the file and read the number, then I would like to input a new number from console. Then add the previous number and inputted number together. For example, the numeber already in file is 5, then I enter 10, I want to write 15 the the file and loop again. My code is listed below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << "Please enter a new number" << endl;
    while (getline(cin, s)) {
        if (s.empty()) {
            break;
        }
        fstream ff;
        string pre;
        ff.open("file.txt", ios::out | ios::in);
        if (ff.is_open()) {
            // read the pre number
            getline(ff, pre);
            cout << "Pre number: " << pre << endl;
            // Write new number
            int new_number = stoi(pre) + stoi(s);
            ff << new_number << endl;
            // Read the new number
            ff.seekg(ios::beg);
            getline(ff, pre);
            cout << "New number: " << pre << endl;


        }
        ff.close();
    }
    return 0;
```

the problem is it cannot write the input number to the file. Always the existing the number in the file.

```
Please enter a new number
12
Pre number: 78
New number: 78
12
Pre number: 78
New number: 78
12
Pre number: 78
New number: 78
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [std::ostream::seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) to set `ostream` to point to the new location set by `istream` and also use [std::ostream::seekp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/) to set `istream` to point to the new location that `ostream` has set.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [std::fopen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) with `r+,a+` flags for read/write to file.